# how to get the locations of boundary boxes?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

the object detection model https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection
I want to ask a question how to know the boundary bounding box location in the image when I print boxes I get this weird results

```
  [ 0.48789895  0.45768291  0.97402203  0.74386948]
  [ 0.45094413  0.43764329  0.95940024  0.83383584]
  [ 0.4293156   0.21623567  0.99745536  0.98074901]
  [ 0.45155856  0.32218739  0.9560734   0.72862589]
  [ 0.48685527  0.19538105  0.99254048  0.9101665 ]
  [ 0.70316464  0.10483098  0.83862311  0.4784345 ]
  [ 0.66167903  0.05663677  0.94684803  0.48852831]
  [ 0.40414423  0.6952647   0.9623639   0.97174299]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe those bounding boxes are represented as top-left / bottom-right points in the image given in percentages of the image size.

So `[0.48, 0.45, 0.97, 0.74]` is a bounding box covering approximately the center of the image to the bottom and 3/4 of the image to the right. If your image was 256x256 that bounding box would be from pixel `[123, 115]` (height, width) to pixel `[248, 189]`

This is a common representation in object detection models.